# I need to install the package 'cjwplain' on Fedora 17

Tags: installing, plain-tex

I need to compile old books typeset using Plain Tex. But I need to compile them using LaTeX instead of TeX because I need to process them using the package {preview}.

I have found out about a package that makes the promise of working the wonder of doing so without the need to extensively edit the original TeX files. Yeah!

This package is called **cjwplain**. However, I am having a hard time finding the correct install package for my Fedora TeXLive distribution.

I installed the official TeXLive repository for my Fedora 17 distribution in order to have a consistent LaTeX system. but for some reason the package **cjwplain** is not located where it should. And I cannot find it anywhere else in the Fedora repository. Is there anything I am missing?

Supposedly, the package should be bundled with: **texlive-texmf-latex-2007-41.fc17.noarch.rpm** but this file has been obsoleted by **texlive-2012-19.20130317_r29408.fc17.x86_64** wich is already installed in my system. But **cjwplain**is not present.

Maybe I should ask this question at the Fedora forum, but I though I might give a try at this forum first.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain it e.g. here http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/cjw/cjwplain.dtx

Inside there are instructions how to use it.